# How to learn a filter on a dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, reinforcement-learning, latent-variable

Let $X$ be a a tabular dataset with $N$ features indexed by row number and a categorical value `"Cat"`. Let $A$ be an aggregation function, e.g. `.groupby("Cat").count()`, and let $L$ be a real-valued objective function on $A(X)$. What is a good approach to learning a row-level filter $\rho$ for $X$ that minimizes $(L \circ A \circ \rho)(X)$? That is, can we learn which rows to throw out (based on their feature values) that make the score on the aggregated data the lowest?

Comment: Maybe you can produce a small, artificial example of the problem that you have in mind?

Answer (score 1):

This depends a lot on the range of possible objective functions. For arbitrary objective functions, there is no method better than enumeration of all the $2^{len(X)}$ possible filters.

For well-behaved functions $A$ it might work to first generalise from boolean filters to a differentiable version of the problem, where the filter assigns a real weight in $[0.0, 0.1]$ to each row. In that case, you can try to solve by gradient descent.

Alternatively, if there are reasons to stick with a discrete filter, the variety of function $A$ that you are dealing with might leave simulated annealing as a reasonable optimization strategy. Or even genetic programming, if there is a way of deriving a "child" filter from two "parent" filters, that makes sense in your domain.

There's a no free lunch theorem for all machine learning - with no domain knowledge, no learning.